# Special width for border bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm here with a problem I'm trying to solve, you can see more in the screenshot I've uploaded.

I'm trying to set a special border bottom for a  or  text, but the border should have a special width and not cover all the width of the word.

The text is centered in the page, so it's more complex because there will be more texts like this in the page and every text has a different width.

I thought about three solutions:

1) Use a border-bottom, but how I can set the width if every text is always different?

2) Use a hr element but it would not go exactly under the word or at start of the word and if I center it it would go just casual in the middle of the page

3) Using a :after property, but I think also in this case the line would go somewhere casual in the middle of the page and not under the start of the word.

Any suggestions how to make the thing in the screenshot?

[image: see screenshot]

Thank you for every suggestion and for taking the time to answer!
Francesco

Comment: You cannot give a border a width. What you need is absolute positioning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```css
h1{
  position: relative;
}

h1::before{
  content: "";
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the tittle</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which letters you want to underline, you should wrap them in a  and border-bottom this span

Answer (score 0):

Used `:after` pseudo element of this

```css
h1::after{
  content: "";
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the tittle</h1>
```

Comment: Use the flow, Luke. No need for absolute positioning :)